# How to redirect to flutter app from spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, flutter, spring-security, flutter-web

I have been working with Spring Boot and FLutter. I am working with `password-reset` functionality. I want that when a user requests to reset the password an email is sent to the user's email address and after clicking on the `link` the backend service will validate the **token** and redirect to the flutter app page where the user could enter the **New Password**.

Everything is going well but I am unable to redirect to the flutter web page.

**Controller.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/forgot-password", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String forgotUserPassword(@RequestParam("emailId") String emailId) {
        User existingUser = userRepository.findByEmailIdIgnoreCase(emailId);
        if (existingUser != null) {
            ConfirmationToken confirmationToken = new ConfirmationToken(existingUser);
            confirmationTokenRepository.save(confirmationToken);
            SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
            mailMessage.setTo(existingUser.getEmailId());
            mailMessage.setSubject("Complete Password Reset!");
            mailMessage.setFrom("abc@gmail.com");
            mailMessage.setText("Dear " + existingUser.getFirstName().toUpperCase() + " " + existingUser.getLastName().toUpperCase() + ",\n\n" + "You have requested to reset password. To complete the password reset process, please click here: "
                    + "http://localhost:8082/confirm-reset?token=" + confirmationToken.getConfirmationToken()");

            emailSenderService.sendEmail(mailMessage);

            return "Request to reset password received. Check your inbox for the reset link.";

        } else {
            return "This email does not exist!";
        }

    }


  String emailByPasswordRestToken = null;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/confirm-reset", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public String validateResetToken(@RequestParam("token") String confirmationToken) {
        ConfirmationToken token = confirmationTokenRepository.findByConfirmationToken(confirmationToken);

        if (token != null) {
            User user = userRepository.findByEmailIdIgnoreCase(token.getUser().getEmailId());
            user.setEnabled(true);
            userRepository.save(user);
            emailByPasswordRestToken = user.getEmailId();
            return "valid token";
//here it should return and redirect to the activity of flutter app automatically to enter the `New Password`.
        } else {
            return "This link is broken or expired.";
        }

    }
```

> How could I do so,please.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways of doing the redirect from your controller.

**1. Using the** [`HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)) **method.**

For this, you'll have to change the signature of your `validateResetToken` function, make it `void` and add `HttpServletResponse` parameter:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/confirm-reset", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public void validateResetToken(@RequestParam("token") String confirmationToken,
                                 HttpServletResponse response) {
    // ... your logic ...

    response.sendRedirect("http://your-flutter-url/path");
}
```

**2. Simply by adding the** `"redirect:"` **into your response String**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/confirm-reset", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public String validateResetToken(@RequestParam("token") String confirmationToken) {
    // ... your logic ...

    return "redirect:http://your-flutter-url/path"
}
```

**Note:** Not very sure if the redirect will work when the request is `POST`. So I would also change the `RequestMapping` to accept only `GET` requests. You could change it to:

```
@GetMapping("/confirm-reset")
public String validateResetToken(@RequestParam("token") String confirmationToken)
```

Comment: Sir how to set the path of Flutter in app.?  The main problem is how the app comes to know to open the page automatically,

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that. You will have to know what is the URL of your Flutter app (or any other front-end app that you use).